# Netscaler Action - Replace Period with Hyphen

Tags: citrix, netscaler

I am trying to use a Content Switching Action in my netscaler to replace the periods in a domain name with a hyphen.

This is how I am doing this currently;

```
HTTP.REQ.HOSTNAME.BEFORE_STR(".") + "-" + HTTP.REQ.HOSTNAME.DOMAIN.BEFORE_STR(".") + "-" + HTTP.REQ.HOSTNAME.DOMAIN.AFTER_STR(".")
```

Not only does this look really sloppy, but it only works for a 3 part domain name.

EG: it works for "site.domain.com" but not "sub.site.domain.com"

I haven't been able to find a simple .REPLACE(str, result) for the HOSTNAME or DOMAIN parts.

.PATH provides a simple to use .PATH.GET( int_path_part ), but HOSTNAME does not.

I am using version 11.0.69 Netscaler software.

What am I missing here? This seems like it should be simple to do but the Expression Editor seems to handicap my ability to do this.

Comment: if the comment from KaiT doesn't help you, provide me some examples and I will be able to get you something that does what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RE "I haven't been able to find a simple .REPLACE(str, result) for the HOSTNAME or DOMAIN parts."

On a Rewrite Action choose type= Replace_ALL || Replace

You can either do a logical replace with regular expressions or a static replace where you simply have 1 rewrite policy / action for each application. You can also do a KV Pair type of replace where you lookup in a kv pair for what to replace